# Solve two polynomial equations in two unknowns.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following equations :

$$f_x=3y-y^2-2xy=0$$
$$f_y=-x^2+3x-2xy=0$$

I need to find the critical points inorder to find min/max point inside the area.

I get the following points as critical points :

$$(0,0),(0,3),(3,0),(3,3)$$

I'll explain how I managed to reach there :

because :

$$f_x=f_y$$
$$-y(y-3)+x(x-3)=0$$

For some reason in the answer they didn't get $(3,3)$ as a point and instand they got $(1,1)$ as a point on the rest of the points I got the same as the answer, 
$$$$
The problem is that $(1,1)$ is also true since $x=y$ in this case, but I get infitine number of points to check.

Any idea what could be done inorder to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: From $x^2-y^2+3y-3x=0$ you get $(x-y)(x+y-3)=0$ i.e. $x=y$ or $x+y=3$. Putting $x=y$ in the first equation gives $3y-3y^2=0$ i.e. $y=0, 1$

Comment: @MarkBennet Thank you great comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equations are $y(3-y-2x)$ and $x(3-x-2y)=0$. This gives for systems to solve: $y=0\land x=0$,$y=0\land3-x-2y=0$, $3-y-2x=0\land x=0$ and $3-y-2x=0\land 3-x-2y=0$. The solutions are known.

Remember that $(3,3)$ is a solution to only one of the equations, not of both.